# in react native's react-native-timeline-flatlist in imageUrl image is not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I am trying to applying react-native-timeline-flatlist in my screen 
so the problem is that when I put any live image url from any website the image are showing up but when I want to show image from my react native directory then image are not showing up , please tell me where is the problem occuring

here is my data

```
const [data,setData] = useState([
      {
        time: '1st Week', 
        title: 'Your baby is still taking shape.', 
        description: ' ',
        lineColor:'#009688', 
        icon: require('../../assets/icon.png'),
        imageUrl: 'https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/21040043/24240340/c0f96b3a-0fe3-11e7-8964-fe66e4d9be7a.jpg',
      },
      {
        time: '2nd Week', 
        title: 'Your baby is still taking shape.', 
        description: ' ', 
        icon: require('../../assets/icon.png'),
        imageUrl: '../../assets/43/2.png'
      },
      {
        time: '3rd Week', 

        title: 'Your baby is still taking shape.', 
        description: ' ', 
        icon: require('../../assets/icon.png'),
        imageUrl: '../../assets/43/3.png'
      },
     ]);
```

in this data only first image is showing while another 2nd and 3rd image is not showing  up

Answer (score 0):

try with require

```
const [data,setData] = useState([
      {
        time: '1st Week', 
        title: 'Your baby is still taking shape.', 
        description: ' ',
        lineColor:'#009688', 
        icon: require('../../assets/icon.png'),
        imageUrl: 'https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/21040043/24240340/c0f96b3a-0fe3-11e7-8964-fe66e4d9be7a.jpg',
      },
      {
        time: '2nd Week', 
        title: 'Your baby is still taking shape.', 
        description: ' ', 
        icon: require('../../assets/icon.png'),
        imageUrl: require('../../assets/43/2.png')'
      },
      {
        time: '3rd Week', 

        title: 'Your baby is still taking shape.', 
        description: ' ', 
        icon: require('../../assets/icon.png'),
        imageUrl: require('../../assets/43/3.png')
      },
     ]);
```

Comment: I have tried that , this showing error : error while updating property 'src' of a view managed by :RCTImageView

Comment: when you use image in local file you use source={ require('../../assets/43/3.png')} and if you user any URL so use  source={{uri://URL here}}